# unable to push image in docker

Tags: docker

I have made an image using the command `docker build -t my-app-1.0-snapshot .`. When I try to push it to `Docker Hub` from windows `cmd`, I get error

```
docker push manuchadha25/my-app-1.0-snapshot
The push refers to repository [docker.io/manuchadha25/codingjediweb-1.0-snapshot]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: manuchadha25/my-app-1.0-snapshot
```

When I tried just using the name of the image without my username, I get `access denied` error

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/codingjediweb-1.0-snapshot]
5bd738db4dd5: Preparing                                                                                                 a57994b863ef: Preparing                                                                                                 85802b819ba0: Preparing                                                                                                 3cb3e7a9fe58: Preparing                                                                                                 04dc636f40fe: Preparing                                                                                                 691339400516: Waiting                                                                                                   2ee490fbc316: Waiting                                                                                                   b18043518924: Waiting                                                                                                   9a11244a7e74: Waiting                                                                                                   5f3a5adb8e97: Waiting                                                                                                   73bfa217d66f: Waiting                                                                                                   91ecdd7165d3: Waiting                                                                                                   e4b20fcc48f4: Waiting                                                                                                   denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Then I tried to tag the image using `docker tag my-app-1.0-snapshot:latest coding_jedi_first_deployment:1.00` and then I tried to push it but again got access denied error. I have logged using `docker login` already.

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/my_app_first_deployment]
5bd738db4dd5: Preparing                                                                                                 a57994b863ef: Preparing                                                                                                 85802b819ba0: Preparing                                                                                                 3cb3e7a9fe58: Preparing                                                                                                 04dc636f40fe: Preparing                                                                                                 691339400516: Waiting                                                                                                   2ee490fbc316: Waiting                                                                                                   b18043518924: Waiting                                                                                                   9a11244a7e74: Waiting                                                                                                   5f3a5adb8e97: Waiting                                                                                                   73bfa217d66f: Waiting                                                                                                   91ecdd7165d3: Waiting                                                                                                   e4b20fcc48f4: Waiting                                                                                                   denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

What am I doing wrong>

Answer (score 1):

The image needs to be tagged `manuchadha25/my-app-1.0-snapshot`
Then you can push it with
`docker push manuchadha25/my-app-1.0-snapshot`